# Difference between jQuery selectors "ancestor descendant" and "parent > child"

Tags: jquery

The following two forms of jQuery selectors seem to do the same thing:

- $("div > ul.posts")
- $("div ul.posts")

which is to select all the "ul" elements of class "posts" under "div" elements.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Concerning `$("div > ul.posts")`, only direct descendants of `DIV`s will be selected.

```
<div>
    <ul class="posts"> <!--SELECTED-->
        <li>List Item</li>
        <ul class="posts"> <!--NOT SELECTED-->
            <li>Sub list item</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>

    <fieldset>
        <ul class="posts"> <!--NOT SELECTED-->
            <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>

    <ul class="posts"> <!--SELECTED-->
        <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

while `$("div ul.posts")` will select all descendants matching the criteria. So all and any `ul.posts` will be selected, whatever their nesting level is as long as somewhere along the chain, they are within a `div`.

Comment: Sorry for deletion, the comment was no longer relevant ;)

Comment: I was just surprised you were able to delete it. It looks like you can delete comments under your own posts, news to me! Take care.

Comment: I wish the jQuery documentation was as clear as this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The first only selects ul.posts whose parentNode is div.

The second would also select:

```
<div>
    <blockquote>
        <ul class="posts"></ul>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh. So "ancestor descendant" refers to all specified elements under a parent, no matter how deeply nested

While "parent child" refers only to the first specified element even if it occurs again somewhere else under the parent

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding a familiar reference here. I realize it's years after the original question but it was on the first page on Google and maybe this will help someone else.

Think of real-world ancestors and parents. Parent and Child are always one generation apart, but ancestors and their descendants can be hundreds of years apart. The `>` symbol helps symbolize the direct relation between parent and child.